# Can't set automatic downloads on iPod Touch 4g (Required for Find my iPod functionality)

Tags: ipod-touch, find-my-iphone

Settings > Store

The automatic download options for Music and Apps are OFF, and whenever I try to set them ON the switch returns to OFF immediately.

This is supposed to be the last step to set up the Find My iPod app.

The check boxes for these automatic downloads are already checked in iTunes on my Windows 7 machine. iCloud is set on it too. I don't know what to do. I'm signed up in icloud from my iPod and laptop.

Comment: Did you recently have those settings enabled with a different account? Or recently buy it used, so someone else might have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need to turn on automatic updates to activate Find My iPod. Anywho, I suggest you simply log out from your iTunes account and log back in.

Do this by going to Settings > Store and tapping Sign Out. Then Sign back in again.

Comment: Maybe I need to change my question? I concerned only about find my ipod app, but I thought automatic downloads was a must.

Comment: Have you tried signing out an in? Does it still not work? :/ The fact you can't use find my iPod nor turn on automatic downloads might be pointing to the same problem: your iPod, for some reason, is having trouble connecting to your iCloud account. Try signing off and on again, and maybe even restarting your iPod and see how that goes.

Comment: Yes, I tried it all from both answers. How do you sign out from iCloud? I can sign out from the store, but there's not clear way on iCloud options, there's the delete account button only.

Comment: Hmm... I'm thinking in theory you would need to go into Mail, Calendar, Contacts and delete the account associated with iCloud on each one. What are you getting some error from Find My Phone? What are the steps you have followed? I suppose you downloaded the app. What error does it display when you open it? What does the Web App at iCloud.com tell you?

Comment: Whenever i open the Find my IPod app, it tells me that no devices are found. I just went to the ICloud website. The first thing I see is a link directing me to the steps to set up iCloud in my iPod and windows machine. I accomplish every step for my windows machine and every step on the ipod section just before setting up automatic downloads, which is the fourth step.

Comment: Will it let you log in to iCloud? It should... Try logging in and using the web app there. I would also suggest you go to Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > iCloud and make sure the service is on. The other thing I can suggest in case none of this works and you can't log out of iCloud is restoring your iPod. You shouldn't loose any data nor it's hard, but it takes a while, which is a little annoying. Nonetheless I don't think this should be necessary.

Comment: I'll do it anyway. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Ok, keep me posted!

Answer (score -1):

Try signing out of your iTunes account on the iPod. Do a hard reset (hold the home and sleep/wake buttons together until the device turns off, releasing the home button (but still pressing the sleep/wake button) as soon as the device turns off (release the sleep/wake button when the  logo appears). Then sign back in.

Comment: I tried this, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: That's vodoo...